# SwiftUI Instantiate a variable using another variable

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui

I'm trying to create a conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius, which requires me to call on the amount the user chose. Here's what I have so far

```
@State private var temperatureChoices = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit"]
     @State private var startTemp = "Celsius"
     @State private var endTemp = "Fahrenheit"
     @State private var startAmount = 0.0
     @State private var endAmount = 0.0
     let fToC = {
         return (5/9) * (startAmount - 32)
     }
var body: some view{
```

I've tried doing it without the closure, but that doesn't work either. I've tried doing it inside of the body, but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? How do I instantiate a variable using another variable?

Comment: You want a computed property, for `fToC` change it from `let` to `var` and remove the `=`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing, but looks weird to me that you have `@State` for every option. I would expect 1 state property for type of temperature (e.g. `@State private var selectedType: String // "Celsius" or "Fahrenheit"`) and one `@State` for current selection (e.g. `@State private var amount: Double // whatever user chose`, in `selectedType` units). Also consider using `enum` to express "Celsius", "Fahrenheit"

Comment: @George I get two warnings when I do that. Computed property must have an explicit type and Type annotation missing in pattern

Comment: For conversion between celsius and fahrenheit, you can use the Measurement API in Swift.

Comment: try this: `var fToC: Double { (5/9) * (startAmount - 32) }`